# Metric vs Imperial Units in The Expanse

Tags: the-expanse-novels

In Caliban's War, there's a scene where Bobbie is jogging on a ship during her trip to Earth.

> She gave her wristwatch a quick glance. Two hours. At her current leisurely pace, that meant twelve miles. Push for twenty?

Her use of imperial units stuck out to me. Have there been other uses of Imperial units in the series? I haven't noticed any but, as an American, they wouldn't necessarily register as odd to me since I use them every day. I could easily miss a reference to them.

Comment: Are you asking if this is an isolated use of imperial?

Comment: It's definitely not isolated, it's sprinkled throughout.

Comment: This same issue was often raised by viewers of Star Trek TOS

Comment: Doing a quick grep through *Leviathan Wakes* I see metric used for large-scale measurements, and imperial used for personal-scale measurements, like a three-inch scar, or acceleration piling extra pounds on one's chest.

Comment: There are many regions today where both flavors of units are used together.  Canada and the UK are examples of this, where colloquial use of Imperial units continues to be heard even as metric units are used in formal engineering/medical/science contexts.  In America, many engineers are bilingual when it comes to units.  There's no reason to think this won't continue into the future.